# XML in a .log file

Tags: xml, logging, xml-parsing

I have a .log file that is update every 15 minutes on my server, from communication with some mobile units.

Some of the information is text and some xml.

How can I extract the xml, i have tried excel but returns errors, have tried parsing also returns errors.

The data returned looks similar to this for each unit returned every 15 minutes, so by end of day quite a lot of mixed text and xml.

```
2014\09\12 00:00:49.063 | Broadcast
2014\09\12 00:00:49.064 | ClientCount: 1
2014\09\12 00:00:49.064 | ClientID: 0
2014\09\12 00:00:49.065 | ClientName: UK1  ClientType: 6
2014\09\12 00:00:49.065 | nID: 3
2014\09\12 00:00:49.065 | Client Exists
2014\09\12 00:00:49.066 | Client Connected
2014\09\12 00:00:49.066 | CUCMID set
2014\09\12 00:00:49.072 | 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseStatus><Responses><Response><Header><SendRepeat>0</SendRepeat><Timestamp>12.09.2014 00:00:49</Timestamp><OrgaNo>00000</OrgaNo><Transmitter>+447000000000</Transmitter><SourceNo>0000000000000000</SourceNo><TaskType>HST</TaskType><DemandTask>0</DemandTask><CommunicationSystem>T1</CommunicationSystem><CucmID>5</CucmID></Header><Data><HST><SourceTyp>3</SourceTyp><CarID>0</CarID><Timestamp>12.09.2014 00:01:00</Timestamp><TripState>0</TripState><Km>0</Km><Mileage>33</Mileage><DoorBC>0</DoorBC><DoorCar>-1</DoorCar><Ignition>0</Ignition><DataKeyIn>1</DataKeyIn><FuelCardIn>-1</FuelCardIn><BatteryOK>1</BatteryOK><Temperature>-1</Temperature><Registration>1</Registration><SignalQuality>31</SignalQuality><SignalError>99</SignalError><GPRSRegistration>1</GPRSRegistration><ConnectState>2</ConnectState><TrackingMode>-1</TrackingMode><OBDMode>-1</OBDMode><SourceNo>01B758????000003</SourceNo><ReaderState>7143521</ReaderState><SIMID>+447000000000</SIMID><Firmware></Firmware><LEDStatus><Cmd>255</Cmd><State>255</State><Red>1</Red><Yellow>0</Yellow><Green>0</Green><Reason>255</Reason><Info>255</Info></LEDStatus><Battery><Level>1150</Level><Value>1240</Value></Battery><FuelLevel><PerCent>92</PerCent><Total>65535</Total></FuelLevel></HST></Data></Response></Responses></ResponseStatus>
ÿ
```

Any ideas would be great

R

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at LogParser.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx